# Help I can't figure out why this won't unwrap correctly

Tags: uv, error

The unwrap has edges connecting two pieces when I don't think it should and i can't figure out why. T[image]here is also a floating circle which is part of the seam. I've tried cleaning up the mesh, but i'm still missing something. Thanks guys!
[owl.blend1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vtzl8j2cRYvxSzqWkxxrNYI56_Xpc4T9/view?usp=sharing,%20)
[owl.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_uQSvvP2J-ZRp9jIqvCIwX-tJaWKjboq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your files are private

Comment: SORRY. I fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eanix says, your topology is not correct, here it looks like you have 2 faces but you've actually got only one face, and the edge just overlays, it does not separate the face in 2 different ones, it just join 2 vertices of this 7 vertex face. Maybe you thought you were separating the face (with <kbd>J</kbd>) when actually you were just joining 2 vertices (with <kbd>F</kbd>):

[image]

If I delete the face, you'll even see that this edge is actually part of an inner face:

[image]

So delete this inner face as well and refill 2 separate faces. More generally, check your whole topology, for example it's better to only use quads.

[image]

Comment: Ahah! THANKS. I just couldn't find it. I knew i was making a simple mistake!

Answer (score 0):

There's a face within your mesh which shouldn't be there and the edges don't connect properly.

Comment: Which mesh is it? Illustrate please.